# When MySQL tells me "Access Denied", why does it think my username is ''?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I've just installed MySQL on OS X Lion through Homebrew, and followed the post-install instructions.  Now I need to make a database:

```
$ mysql -u peeja
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 5.5.25a Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `new_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'new_db'
```

What's up with `user ''@'localhost'`?  Why not `user 'peeja'@'localhost'`?  And why doesn't this Just Work™ for the installing user?  Isn't that how Homebrew is supposed to set it up?

Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Don't know, but maybe don't use a space: `mysql -upeeja`

Comment: In addition to the answers you have received, it is probably a good idea to drop the anonymous user.

Comment: I didn't even know there *was* an anonymous user. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connected as anonymous user - ''@'localhost'. This user is created on your server.
And you do not have created user 'peeja'@'localhost'. By default MySQL connect uses anonymous account.

So, connect as root and create user -

```
CREATE USER 'peeja'@'localhost';
```

Then grant privileges you need and reconnect as 'peeja'@'localhost'.

Comment: D'oh!  The instructions say that the *server* will run as my user, not that it'll create a user with my name automatically (which the Postgres formula does).  Thanks for the explanation; I didn't realize it would fallback to an anonymous user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no user `peeja` without a password so it logs you as anonymous. If that user exists then log as:

```
mysql -u peeja -p mypassword
```

or

```
mysql -u peeja -p
```